# 'end' expected (to close 'function' at line 1) near '<eof>'

Tags: lua

I get this error

```
[ERROR] lua/autorun/donor_guns.lua:4: 'end' expected (to close 'function' at line 1) near '<eof>'
```

1. unknown - lua/autorun/donor_guns.lua:0

when running this script

```
hook.Add( "PreDrawViewModel", "ReplaceCrowbar", function( vm, ply, weapon )
if ( ply:GetNWString( "usergroup" ) == "donor" and weapon = "weapon_ttt_caliburn" then
vm:SetModel( "models/tiggomods/weapons/SATBK/v_Caliburn.mdl" )
end
```

any help?

Comment: I've never seen a better compiler error message. Have you read it?

Comment: If your compiler/interpreter parser tells you that you're missing an `end`, you're probably missing an `end`.

Comment: Bad at coding but I got it now

Comment: you might have added `else if` instead of `elseif`

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a 'end' closure to your function declaration ,a ')' to end your function call, a '='  to your second equality test and '(' after if is useless and not closed. It should be :

```
hook.Add( "PreDrawViewModel", "ReplaceCrowbar", 
function( vm, ply, weapon )
   if ply:GetNWString( "usergroup" ) == "donor" and weapon == "weapon_ttt_caliburn" then
      vm:SetModel( "models/tiggomods/weapons/SATBK/v_Caliburn.mdl" )
   end 
end
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're short of an `end`, as the compiler so clearly tells you.

A `lua` conditional statement looks like this:

```
if <condition> then
   <statements...>
end
```

And a function is like this

```
function foo(params)
   <statements...>
end
```

Also, your brackets don't match.

Comment: so it should look like hook.Add( "PreDrawViewModel", "ReplaceCrowbar", function( vm, ply, weapon )
if ( ply:GetNWString( "usergroup" ) == "donor" and weapon = "weapon_ttt_caliburn" then
vm:SetModel( "models/tiggomods/weapons/SATBK/v_Caliburn.mdl" )
end
end )

Comment: Almost. Count your brackets (open vs. close) , as you're still mismatched.

Comment: You have `if (... then`. instead of `if (...) then`

Comment: [ERROR] lua/autorun/donor_guns.lua:2: ')' expected near '='
  1. unknown - lua/autorun/donor_guns.lua:0

Comment: Same rule applies but he's got a [function declaration expression](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.10) not a function declaration statement.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread. Just had the same problem and wanted to add another possible point of failure - check your "if-else" statements, namely your "elseif"s. I have just spent half an hour trying to find "missing" end, because "else if" was written with a space, which apparently looks like a totally separate IF statement to the Lua -_-